# Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-4.0

I have installed the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.1.3 via NuGet. It installed just fine I believe. This is a .NET 4.0 Web Forms Project.

When I try to bundle I get an error. My code in **Application_Start**:

```
var jqueryBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/bundles/jquery");

    jqueryBundle.Include(new string[] { 
        "~/scripts/libs/jquery/jq/jquery-1.11.0.min.js",
        "~/scripts/swyft/mobileinit.min.js",
        "~/scripts/libs/jquery/jqm/142/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js",
    });

    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(jqueryBundle);
```

Then on one of my aspx pages...

```
<%= System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/scripts/bundles/jquery") %>
```

Gives me this error:

> An unexpected error has occurred. 
>       Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

But it is there! I am running VS2013.

Thanks for any help!

~Red

**EDIT - My WebConfig:**

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  ...
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  ...
</assemblyBinding>
```

**EDIT - CANNOT INSTALL Web Grease 1.5.1:**

When I try to install Web Grease 1.5.1 I get this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At L:\MY_PROJECT_PATH\packages\WebGrease.1.5.1\tools\install.ps1:45 char:5
+     $msbuild.Xml.AddProperty("WebGreaseLibPath", $relativePackageUri.ToString(). ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

** EDIT - ADD package.config FILE **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="AjaxControlToolkit" version="7.1213" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="AjaxMin" version="5.10.5260.16959" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.4.6" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.WebForms" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

**Edit - Added SS of Error**

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: What does it look like in your Web.Config

Comment: Is it the same version?

Comment: There's a version mismatch there. When you build the application do you see any Build Warnings (not errors) that say 'Found conflicts between different versions of the same assembly...'

Comment: I see that now. But to answer your question, no, I got no warning or error :(

Comment: So after trying to install version 1.5.1 specifically, I get the error added in my post :( Ughhhhh.....

Comment: But your web.config says 1.5.2 and not 1.5.1?

Answer (score 8):

Since the latest versions apparently have dependency problems, I reluctantly went back to older versions of Optimization and Webgrease using these commands in NuGet Package Manager Console:

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
Uninstall-Package WebGrease
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Version 1.1.0
Install-Package WebGrease -version 1.3
```

This combination worked for me, but there might be other combinations.

Comment: Feels bad to be downgrading, but this was the only thing that worked for us.  MS say this is fixed.  Doesn't seem to be: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806534/system-web-optimization-dll-v1-1-from-nuget-claims-to-require-webgrease-dll-v1-5-2-14234-but-has-broken-reference-to-older-webgrease

Answer (score 1):

I think the version is different for both the `WebGrease` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` are different. so, try to uninstall both and update these with `Nuget`. After uninstalling verify your package.config file both the versions are removed or not. After that Update and observe the web.config files.

Try executing the following commands in the package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
Update-Package WebGrease
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
Uninstall-Package WebGrease
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
Update-Package WebGrease
```

If its not work then verify the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` and remove it and re-install thid again

Comment: So I followed the steps exactly, please not this not a MVC project, but a Web Forms one. Anyway, it did not work. I get an error referencing ver 1.5.1 for some reason. I think the Web Opt one is dependent on 1.5.2 which will not install. See the image I have added. Thanks for your try!

Comment: thank you this worked. For me, version 1.5.2 worked great with the same commands that you had

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization will not work with Web Grease 1.5.1, so installing that version will not help.  Try uninstalling both packages using the Nuget Console (Finding and Installing a NuGet Package Using the Package Manager Console)[[http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console]](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console%5d).

Then manually install Web Grease 1.6.  Then install Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3

Comment: So I followed your steps exactly. No dice. I was installing 1.5.1 because of the error message I am about to show you. "Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: Can you add your package.config?  It sounds like there might be another package that depends on WebGrease